# solr 8 "msg":"ERROR: unknown field 'language'"

Tags: solr

While updating solr 4 to solr 8, I am facing the error bellow when I am running the indexation to index my solr 8 cloud.

```
    {
      "responseHeader":{
       "rf":1,
        "status":400,
       "QTime":118},
       "error":{
       "metadata":[
          "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
          "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
          "msg":"ERROR: [doc=16919!1379235912] unknown field     'language'",
"code":400}}
```

I run thie url

```
    curl -s 'http://localhost:8983/solr/currnet1/update/csv?commit=true&separator=%09&escape=%5c&header=false&+fieldnames=id,doc_id' -H  'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8' --data-binary @/Users/smukena/Projet/servers/solr-8.1.1/tsv/sampleFile.tsv
```

and my sampleFile.tsv has only one line with two column

There is no the field language in my schema.xml and in solrconfig.xml neiether.

What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 4):

To fix this issue, I had to remove the processor **LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory** in my solrconfig.xml.

This processor adds the ability to detect the language of a document before indexing and then make appropriate decisions about analysis, etc.

By setting it in solrconfig.xml,

```
    <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="langid.fl">title,subject,text,keywords</str>
        <str name="langid.langField">language</str>
      </lst> 
   </processor>
```

solr was expecting the definition of the field language in the schema.xml field that I did not have.

So either remove that processor in solrconfig.xml or add language field in schema.xml

Ref: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/LanguageDetection

Comment: got the same error. as per doc link added `<bool name="langid">false</bool>`  under <1st> node - to disable it. delete and create the core again for it to reflect. then it worked. thanks.